# How to add subfolder to a repo that has a different repo

Tags: git, github

I have a directory that I have been using Git to track changes in it. In that folder I downloaded a tool off of Github which has its original Github info. I can't add its files to my repo which is the parent directory.

Tree structure:

```
DirA (root folder -> git remote bitbucket repo)
 \SubDirA -> included in bitbucket repo
 \SubDirB -> included in bitbucket repo
 \SubDirC -> downloaded from Github, has its own repo info, NOT added to bitbucket repo
```

I'd like to merge SubDirC into my bitbucket repo and remove and Github references within it that might cause problems with commits. What should I do to accomplish this?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: I think you want here is [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)